# flutter build appbundle "can't find dynamically referenced class android.util.LongArray"

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

While running `flutter build appbundle` in my Flutter app, my build fails with this error:

```
Note: io.flutter.view.AccessibilityViewEmbedder$ReflectionAccessors: can't find dynamically referenced class android.util.LongArray
Note: there were 1 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.  
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
```

The closest thing I've found about this is this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/9321).

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to go about resolving this issue? Can I update my android.jar file to include the [LongArray.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/util/LongArray.java) file somehow? Should I figure out where the `LongArray` class is referenced and try to delete it?

It's hard to make an MRE for something like this, but any pointers would be helpful.

(PS. I'm using Android Studio on Linux to develop the app.)

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with the same issue at the moment of building my app.
According to this git post [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37441) is flutter.jar related. You just need to add

```
-dontwarn io.flutter.embedding.**
```

to your /android/app/proguard-rules.pro file in the project folder.

> This is because flutter.jar doesn't bring the AndroidX dependencies.

UPDATE: with flutter 1.9.1+hotfi.2 there is a new error related with WindowInsets. A workaround is add `-dontwarn android.**` in the file mentioned.
Info: [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40168)